# SQL big query optimalization

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT `Product_has_ProductFeature`.`productId`, `Product_has_ProductFeature`.`productFeatureId`, `Product_has_ProductFeature`.`productFeatureValueId`
FROM `Product_has_ProductFeature`
WHERE `productId` IN (...'18815', '18816', '18817', '18818', '18819', '18820', '18821', '18822', '18823', '18824', '18825', '18826', '18827', '18828', '18829', '18830', '18831', '18832', '18833', '18834'..)
```

I have around 50000 productId's. The execution is 20 seconds long. How can I make it faster?

Comment: Are your product ids all consecutive?  Are they integers or strings?

Comment: They are integers, but no consecutives

Comment: where do you get the product ids from for the IN restriction? are those coming from another previous query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a comment.

Returning 50,000 rows can take time, depending on your application, the row size, the network, and how busy the server is.

When doing comparisons, you should be sure the values are of the same type.  So, if `productId` is numeric, then drop the single quotes.

If the values are all consecutive, then eschew the list and just do:

```
where productid >= 18815 and productid <= 18834
```

Finally, an index on `productid` is usually recommended.  However, in some cases, an index can make performance worse.  This depends on the size of your data and the size of memory available for the page and data cache.

MySQL implements `in` efficiently (using a binary tree).  It is possible that much of the overhead is in compiling the query rather than executing it.  If you have the values in a table, a `join` is probably going to be more efficient.